# Asymptotic Analysis of Nested Loops with Conditionals

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I'm trying to run an analysis of a set of nested loops so that I can determine the value of variable `sum` after the outer loop is finished. The code is as follows:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++) {
    if (j % i == 0) {
      for (k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        sum++
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this code is in C++. I have no problem doing this sort of analysis via summations for each loop, but the nested 'if' conditional is throwing me off. Here's what I have so far:

- The 3rd loop is only entered if `j` is equal to or a multiple of `i`.
- The outer and innermost loops have simple bounds that can easily be solved via summation.

Where I get hung up is in regard to defining the lower and upper bounds for the second loop when representing via summation. My current equation is:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{???}^{i*i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}$

I'm subtracting 1 from the upper bounds since the lower bounds start at 0, not 1.

Does anyone have any advice on how to represent this set of nested loops as summations that I can solve to determine the final value of sum? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: Nested sums with the `if`. Step 2: Try to express the terms for which the `if` is false; subtract them.

Comment: Exact duplicate of a recent question, therefore most likely homework.

Comment: In C/C++, `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)` runs $n$ times (count the 0!)

Answer (score 2):

The condition `i % j == 0` is satisfied when `j` is equal to `m * i` for each `m = 0, ..., i - 1`. Therefore, the condition in the second loop will be satisfied `i` times. In form of summation this can be written as:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \sum_{k=0}^{j * i - 1}$

Moreover, your code is equivalent to:

```
sum = 0
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k < j * i; k++) {
        sum++;
      }
  }
}
```